# How to handle GET request with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new to ruby on rails, just run the examples https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails

I would like to modify the code to handle GET request as following:

- For GET articles?special=false, return all articles
- For GET articles?special=true, return all articles that has
  "token" in the title

bin/rails routes
                     articles GET /articles(.:format) articles#index

===app/controllers/articles_controller.rb

```
                 class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
                 def index
                 @articles = Article.all
                 end
```

=== app/views/articles/index.html.erb

```
         <% @articles.each do |article| %>

         <%= article.title %>
         <%= article.text %>
         <%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %>

         <% end %>
```

============routes.rb=====

```
           Rails.application.routes.draw do
           get 'welcome/index'

           resources :articles

            root 'welcome#index'
            end
```

Comment: You can use ruby code in your search you could write something like `Article.select {|article| article.title == 'THE TITLE YOUR LOOKING FOR' }`

Comment: Where do I parse the parameter, in index.html.erb?

Comment: You could change the def index to `@articles = Article.select...` instead of `@articles = Article.all`

Comment: Then the index can only return all articles with certain string in the title. How can I get all articles back, with the same index?

Answer (score 1):

So you could do something like this,

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  @some_articles = @articles.select {|article| article.title == 'SOME STRING'}
end
```

then your view you could create a second loop

```
<div>
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= article.title %>
  <%= article.text %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %>
<% end %>
</div>

<div>
<% @some_articles.each do |some_article| %>
   <%= some_article.title %>
   <%= some_article.text %>
   <%= link_to 'Show', article_path(some_article) %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I mean really the possibilities are pretty limitless(I may not also understand your question to it's fullest potential).

You should check out [this documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more info on database queries in rails, and I don't know if you have seen the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) which is a great starting place and may help you(not sure if you read through it yet)

Comment: What does your routes.rb file look like, and also I am guessing that your GET "token" needs to be dynamic?

Comment: Not really, token can be fixed string. The article ID needs to be dynamic.

Comment: The routes.rb is the same as the toturail. I posted above.